# The fastest way to remove elements from a hash based on specific key/value's

Tags: ruby

I have a **large** array of `order_id` strings:

```
order_ids = ["1", "2", "5", ...]
```

I also have a **large** array of `order` hashes:

```
orders = [{order_id: "1", name: "John"}, {order_id: "3", name: "Bob"}, ...]
```

`orders_ids` represent orders that I need to remove from my `orders` array. So in the above example I need to remove `{order_id: "1", name: "John"}`. But the size of the arrays can be 1M+, so I need a better way than to just iterate through the arrays one by one.

Comment: You'll have to look at each Hash in order to determine if you should remove it. Unless you have some sort of an index mapping order_ids to specific indices in your Array you'll just have to go through all of them, I don't think there's much else you can do.

Comment: How do you filter you orders? It's probably much easier to do it there than to make some custom filtering.

Comment: Hi @limelights. The orders come in from an external source. They will usually be sorted by `order_id`, but as you see they are string objects. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can remove elements from both your `order_ids` and `orders` arrays and assuming that your `orders` array doesn't contain duplicate ids you can remove items from both arrays to make the inclusion check faster as it goes:

```
order_ids = %w[1 3 5 7 9]
orders = [
  {order_id: "1", name: "Abe"},
  {order_id: "2", name: "Bob"},
  {order_id: "3", name: "Clara"},
  {order_id: "4", name: "Daniel"},
  {order_id: "5", name: "Erika"}
]

orders.delete_if do |order|
  break if order_ids.empty?
  index = order_ids.index(order[:order_id])
  order_ids.slice!(index) unless index.nil?
end

p orders     #=> [{:order_id=>"2", :name=>"Bob"}, {:order_id=>"4", :name=>"Daniel"}]
p order_ids  #=> ["7", "9"]
```

Also consider making `order_ids` a [Set](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) which is a better alternative for making inclusion checks. This implementation is probably faster than the previous one:

```
require "set"

# Convert `order_ids` to a set in order to make inclusion checks faster
order_ids = %w[1 3 5 7 9].to_set

# `orders` is the same array as in the previous example

orders.delete_if do |order|
  break if order_ids.empty?
  order_ids.delete? order[:order_id]
end

p orders     #=> [{:order_id=>"2", :name=>"Bob"}, {:order_id=>"4", :name=>"Daniel"}]
p order_ids  #=> #<Set: {"7", "9"}>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. However, what if the `order_ids` array was `%w[3 1 9 7 5]`? Then the `slice` method would "slice of" too much, right?

Comment: No, it would work as well. The only difference would be that `p order_ids  #=> ["9", "7"]` at the end. The `slice` method is slicing  at most one value from the `order_ids` array at a time.

Comment: I initially missed your last sentence. I think that's sufficiently important that you should include it in your code (and if you do, don't forget to show the `require`). Note also that you can terminate as soon as `order_ids` is empty. Lastly, if values of `:order_id` in the hash are not unique, converting `order_id` to a set will still speed things up.

Comment: Those are good points. I tweaked the code and added an example using a set.

Comment: Instead of saying something is "probably faster" show a benchmark proving whichever is faster. See [the Fruity gem](https://github.com/marcandre/fruity) for more information about how easy it is to do that.

Comment: You raise a valid point. It is known that checking for inclusion on a set is faster than checking for inclusion on an array for the general case. That means that the loop using a set should go faster than the loop using an array, but to use a set you first have to construct it from the original array (which will take some extra time). Since I don't have the original array I can't accurately benchmark and see if the time/memory invested in turning the array into a set justifies the subsequent gain in the lookup code.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you plan to reorganize your data into some kind of tree or stack (which will eat a lot of memory just in conversion), you're better off to divide and conquer using the `#reject` method.

```
orders = [{order_id: "1", name: "John"}, {order_id: "3", name: "Bob"}]

order_ids = ["1", "2", "5"]

orders.reject { |val| order_ids.include?(val[:order_id]) }
```

output:

```
{:order_id=>"3", :name=>"Bob"}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to spend a little extra memory, you can reduce this to a linear-time operation.

```
order_map = orders.each_with_object({}) {|order, obj| obj[order["order_id"]] = order }
orders.each {|order| order_map.delete order }
filtered_orders = order_map.values
```